# ASP.NET CORE : Unable to resolve service for type 'API.SQLConnection.IDBConnection' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.UsersController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've started to mess around with ASP.NET Core, ive been using dependency injection to inject the configuration into my Controller class but its giving me the following error:

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'API.SQLConnection.IDBConnection' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.UsersController'

**Users controller (UserController.cs)**

```
  public class UsersController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly IDBConnection _isqlConnection;
    private readonly DataContext _context; // here we have used dependency injection so that we can access the data from the DataContext class.
    public UsersController(DataContext context)
    {         
        _context = context;
    }
    public UsersController(IDBConnection connection) 
    {
        _isqlConnection = connection;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppUser>>GetUsers() // we are going to be returning a type of action result. 
    {
        _isqlConnection.GetConnection().Open();
        var user = _context.Users.ToList();
        _isqlConnection.GetConnection().Close();
        return user;
       
    }
```

**Start up (Startup.cs)**

```
 public class Startup
 {
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });           
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }
```

**AppUser (AppUser.cs)**

```
public class AppUser 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

**DataContext (DataContext.cs)**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }        
}
```

**DBConnection (DBConnection.cs)**

```
public interface IDBConnection 
{
    SqlConnection GetConnection();
    
}
public class DBConnection : IDBConnection
{
    public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DatingSite;Integrated Security=True");
    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return con;
    }

}
```

Not really sure what is wrong does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd not suggest reusing same `SqlConnection`, `ADO.NET` will do that for you behind the scenes even if you'll create a new one all the time. Secondly, you don't need to open and close connection. Just return `_context.Users.ToList()`, dependency injection will close conn for you

Comment: Thankyou @AndriyShevchenko for the advice, I've made those changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that you need to register the service with the dependency injection container, since you are using it for dependency injection. In `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices()`, try to add:

`services.AddScoped<IDBConnection, DBConnection>();`

Comment: Thankyou, thats helped solve the problem, but I'm having another issue now lol

Comment: Glad it helped for the initial problem at least lol. What is the new problem? If it is not briefly explained, feel free to create a new question/thread, then I will jump in there to see if I can help.

Comment: Thank you. I've only asked one question today and stackoverflow is telling me that I've reached my question limit already :/......The Error is: ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 83...…its referring to the line "return _context.Users.ToList();"  in the GetUsers() function in the UsersController class.

Comment: @vinny1992 Hmm, it's not an exception I am generally familiar with, but I would assume that it has something to do with your DataContext. I may be wrong, but it could be a problem, that you in `Startup.cs` get the `DefaultConnection` from config/appsettings-file, but in `DBConnection`, you specify data source etc in a new SqlConnection. If I were you, I would browse around and see how people specify connectionstrings, both here on SO, GitHub etc. If you still have the problem tomorrow, make a question and I will make sure to check in. Hope it helps =)

Comment: Also, in your controller, is there a special reason, why you make two constructors instead of one? You should initialize both the context and the IDBConnection inside the same constructor to ensure, that both are initialized.

Comment: @vinny1992 The problem could be how your connection-string is specified in appSettings.json (that `options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));` refers to). It may have a minor flaw or something.

Comment: @mnm thankyou for the reply, honestly you've been a great help. I've managed to sort the issue, the format of the connection string was incorrect. -  and yes i noticed both the constructors as i got another error regarding that haha. Thanks again! :)